Isolate matrix in the middle by rearranging terms
I wish to isolate the terms $\vec{x}\vec{x}^\intercal$ from the below expression.  I wish to do this in order to find some sort of closed form for combining $A$ and $B$.
$$A\vec{x}\vec{x}^\intercal A + B\vec{x}\vec{x}^\intercal B $$
$A$ and $B$ are square, symmetric matrices, as is $(\vec{x}\vec{x}^\intercal)$.
Is it possible to isolate $\vec{x}\vec{x}^\intercal$?  If so, how?
Note: Vectorization has been suggested in a similar question here, though I wish to avoid this: How to isolate the matrix in the middle of an equation?

I have got as far as this as an attempt:
$$A(A^{-1} (A\vec{x}\vec{x}^\intercal A + B\vec{x}\vec{x}^\intercal B)B^{-1})B $$
$$= A( \vec{x}\vec{x}^\intercal A B^{-1} + A^{-1}B\vec{x}\vec{x}^\intercal)B $$

As a background, the above expression comes from my attempt to build a mean squared error function from a cone equation $\vec{x}^\intercal C\vec{x}$ below:
$$(\vec{x}^\intercal C\vec{x})^2 =  \vec{x}^\intercal C\vec{x}\vec{x}^\intercal C\vec{x} $$
Adding the mean squared errors of two cones results in:
$$(\vec{x}^\intercal C_1\vec{x})^2 + (\vec{x}^\intercal C_2\vec{x})^2 $$
$$ = \vec{x}^\intercal C_1 \vec{x}\vec{x}^\intercal C_1 \vec{x} + \vec{x}^\intercal C_2 \vec{x}\vec{x}^\intercal C_2 \vec{x}  $$
$$ = \vec{x}^\intercal ( C_1 \vec{x}\vec{x}^\intercal C_1 + C_2 \vec{x}\vec{x}^\intercal C_2)\vec{x}  $$
...here I required help.

But vectorization turns out to be the natural way to do this.

@Abezhiko if that is the case, I would welcome your answer using Vectorization.  I have to confess I do not have an intuitive understanding of Vectorization, and hoped there might be a way to leverage what I know.  If I have to learn something new, so be it!

Matrices act as linear operators on a vector space, but they form a vector space too, in such a way that you can define a linear "superoperator" $-$ in other words, an endomorphism acting on the said matrix space $-$, such as $L_A(X) := AXA$ for instance, hence the formal "factorization" $(L_A+L_B)\vec{x}\vec{x}^T$ for the expression you want to simplify.
Yet, these manipulations are usually considered within the formalism of vectorization. As said above, matrices form a vector space; in consequence, you can recast them as column vectors by choosing a basis. The particular choice of basis where the columns of a matrix $X$ are concatenated in order to form a big column  vector $\operatorname{vec}(X)$ is called the vectorization.
With this definition, the matrix multiplication becomes a Kronecker product, as it follows : $\operatorname{vec}(XYZ) = (Z^T \otimes X)\operatorname{vec}(Y)$. In consequence, the matrix representation of $L_A$ with respect to  the vectorized basis is given by $A^T \otimes A$, hence
$$
\operatorname{vec}(A\vec{x}\vec{x}^TA + B\vec{x}\vec{x}^TB) = (A^T \otimes A + B^T \otimes B)\operatorname{vec}(\vec{x}\vec{x}^T)
$$
in the end.

That is a really good explanation, thank you.  It's a really good introduction to Kronecker products that I haven't been able to take from the Wikipedia article on the subject.
Having played around with the rules for this, I can see that Vectorization / Kron gives me more scope to play around with Matrices.  Nice addition to my toolset.

@TommyK. Glad to help ;) You may accept my answer for future people seeking an answer to the same problem.
